# Any way to download all github repositories of user?

Tags: php

Is there any way to automatically download all repositories from specific user?

Maybe there could be a simple script for PHP or a windows app/tool?

p.s. Please dont link API libraries, I just want for regular computer user, not for building the tool myself.

Comment: Does https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net help?

Comment: @mjwills thanks, but i dont want to spend time building for things, i just wanted to know is there is existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems for PHP this code does the job (without need to install API LIBRARIES or spending much time):

```
Function Download_all_github_files($github_username){
    set_time_limit(0); $final_url = 'http://github.com/' . $github_username . '?tab=repositories'; $folder = basename($github_username); if (!file_exists($folder)){ mkdir($folder, 0755, true);} 
    preg_match_all('/\&lt;a href=\"(.*?)\" itemprop\=\"name/i',get_data($final_url),$n); if(false) exit(var_dump(get_data($final_url)));
    foreach ($n[1] as $each_Url){file_put_contents(__DIR__."/".$folder."/".basename($each_Url).".zip", get_data('https://github.com'.$each_Url.'/archive/master.zip'));}
    echo 'Downloading finished. Open &lt;a href="./'.$folder.'"&gt;folder&lt;/a&gt;';
    } Function get_data($url){ $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 Safari/534.30"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 9); $follow_allowed= ( ini_get('open_basedir') || ini_get('safe_mode')) ? false:true; if ($follow_allowed){curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);}$output = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); return $output;
}
```

usage:

```
echo Download_all_github_files("github_username");
```